# Assigning a UIPickerView in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is empty after showing ModalView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview, lifecycle

I assign a `UIPickerView` in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This is because I assign it view a tag. It works when the view first loads, however, when I present a modal view controller, then dismiss it and return to the view containing the table with the `UIPickerView`, the picker is empty (has no values). I tried `[tableView reloadData` in `ViewWillAppear` thinking it would reassign the picker with its values in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` but it doesnt. I assign the picker object with the following code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell * cell = nil;

    [cell = createPickerCell];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;

}

-(UITableViewCell *) createPickerCell{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPickerCell];
    self.picker.delegate=self;
    self.picker.dataSource =self;
    self.picker = (UIPickerView *)[cell viewWithTag:223];
    NSLog(@"picker tag is %ld",(long)self.picker.tag);
    [cell addSubview:self.stylistPicker];

    return cell;
}
```

If anything is unclear then please ask.

Comment: You should make a protocol in your ModalVC and make the VC with the tableView its delegate. Then when you dismiss the modalVC you can call a protocol-method and make your data reload when your modalVC is actually dismissed. ViewWillAppear won't be called after dismissing a ModalVC

Comment: @TotumusMaximus ViewWillAppear of the presenting view (the view that presents the vc) is called.

Comment: You are creating (custom)cells in a rather weird way. Try making a subclass of UITableViewCell and put the picker there. Then you can normalise your cellForRowAtIndexPath:. I'd read up on some tutorials on how to make UITableViews and CustomCells if I were you. I think the error lies somewhere in there.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus this isnt my usual way of creating a custom cell but it was the only way I could get a UIPickerView to work. But as you can tell it only works when you navigate to the view, not back....for some reason

Comment: @TotumusMaximus it looks like that i need to call the delegate method again, or refresh it, in order to call the contents again, is this possible?

Comment: You can always call the delegate methods from anywhere you want. And to reload your UITableViews contents with the array you give it, you will use the reloadData-method.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus I resolved the problem. It was very very easy (I had a brain fart moment I think). Please see below incase you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem, it was very very simple. Instead of assigning it via a tag in the cell, it was much easier to just create the picker view in the cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) createPickerCell{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kPickerCell];
    self.picker = [UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 163)];// new line
    self.picker.delegate=self;
    self.picker.dataSource =self;
    [cell addSubview:self.stylistPicker];

    return cell;
```

}